# Error: Invalid OpenGraph type: product in NextJs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, meta-tags

i have a problem in NextJs 13 when add product in meta's head I get this error

**Error: Invalid OpenGraph type: product**

> NextJS version : 13.4.10

my value in API is :

```
{

  title: 'test',

  openGraph: {

    locale: 'en_US',

    type: 'product',

    title: 'test',

    url: 'https://www.example.com/product/test/',
    site_name: 'example',
    updated_time: '2023-10-29T09:59:40+03:30'

  },

  product: { price: 'USD', availability: 'instock' },

}
```

Comment: *Please provide more details, What API ?*

Comment: @Beast80K - I am running into this same issue too. The API that the data came from is irrelevant. The issue has to do with `OpenGraphProduct` missing in NextJS's `Metadata` TypeScript types.